# Grunt project.json file conflicting with Nuget

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, gruntjs, nuget, visual-studio-2015

We have a grunt file that includes package.json and project.json file for configuration that we have added to our .NET 4.5.1 project in VS2015. The Grunt tasks work fine, however the project.json/package.json file seems to be creating issues when working with Nuget.

Whenever updating or installing, Nuget adds the dependency to the grunt project.json, instead of packages.config. It also plays havoc when restoring packages, which is especially annoying during the automated build/deploy process. It is my understanding that Nuget will use package.json for dependencies in .NET 5, so I'm a bit confused as to whats going on.

Is there any neat way to ensure that Nuget uses packages.config whilst the project.json/package.json files exists in the project.

Currently we've had to move the grunt files into a subfolder to ensure that Nuget always uses packages.config. But now the TaskRunner doesn't recognize the Gruntfile.js anymore.

One of the errors getting thrown while having the project.json/package.json in the root folder:
`You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author. 0`